# Splitting ToC into two parts, each in one page

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, page-breaking

The Table of Contents in my LyX document is multiple pages long, but LyX splits it at an undesirable position. I want to split the Table of Contents manually. An equivalent to `\newpage` but only inside ToC. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: related: [Keep chapter headings and related subheadings in the same page in ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106289/579)

Answer (score 3):

You could add the following to your LaTeX preamble:

```
\newcommand{\tocclearpage}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage}}
```

and then add an ERT containing

```
\tocclearpage
```

*in your document* wherever you wish to insert a page break - `\clearpage` - in your ToC.

The motivation behind this approach is that you have no clear handle on the ToC other than by feeding it instructions throughout your document. That is, the entire ToC is created (in general), using a single macro.

Comment: not sure whether this applies with lyx, but still worth mentioning.  if the job is produced from multiple files pulled in with `\include`, an instruction meant for the toc that is placed before an `\include` statement will not take effect until *after* the `\include'd file is processed, giving a result other than what is wanted.  the toc-adjustment must be placed *within* the `\include`d file, preferably as the first line, and certainly before any command that would put an entry in the toc.